# How do you make a pandas dataframe be filled randomly with 1s and 0s?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I have a
[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foV5v.png) in python that I would like to fill with 1s and 0s based on random choices.
If possible, I'd like it to be done with numpy. I've tried

```
tw['tw'] = np.random.choice([0, 1])
```

but this ends up just giving me a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Pn3.png) filled with either a 1 or a 0. I know that this is possible using a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(tw)):
    tw['tw'][i] = np.random.choice([0, 1])
```

But this feels inefficient. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assign a scalar, the value will be broadcasted to all indices.

You need to assign **an array of the size of the Series**.

Use the `size` parameter of [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```py
tw['tw'] = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(tw))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy's [random integer generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

```py
tw['tw'] = np.random.randint(low = 0,high = 2,size = len(tw))
```

Note that the "high" number is non-inclusive, so you'd have to give 2.